# Limit maximum page length in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, vuetify.js

I have a Vue application running Vuetify but neither of these seem to be equipped to handle my desire to limit the maximum length of the page to be such that there is no scrolling. I hope that makes sense. My hope is to just pull up a screen with a bunch of routing to similarly formatted screens. Of course, the user could make the window smaller, in which case I would need scrolling. So how would I set that up when I want to have the page open to full screen with a maximum page length that will prevent the NEED for scrolling, but still allow scrolling if the need is there due to the user resizing the page to something a good bit smaller?

I spent hours looking around for details on this but didn't find anything that really seemed to be a direct solution. How can I set a max page length? Would CSS offer this? I saw a solution putting CSS in the `<head>`-tag but with a Vue application this head tag doesn't get used in the same way as typical HTML pages.

EDIT: because I don't think it's clear that because I'm working in vue/vuetify the solution might be different from the general case, I think it is best if I provide my App.vue and an example page.

--- App.vue ---

---

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import AppToolbar from "./components/AppToolbar.vue";
import AppFooter from "./components/AppFooter.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
    AppToolbar,
    AppFooter
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  })
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

--- Homepage.vue ---

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app>
      <v-responsive aspect-ratio="16/9">
        <v-carousel cycle hide-delimiter-background show-arrows-on-hover>
          <v-carousel-item
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="i"
            :src="item.src"
            reverse-transition="fade-transition"
            transition="fade-transition"
          ></v-carousel-item>
        </v-carousel>
      </v-responsive>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/squirrel.jpg"
        },
        {
          src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg"
        },
        {
          src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg"
        },
        {
          src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

EDIT 2: Adding the app-toolbar & app-footer

--- Toolbar.vue ---

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <v-toolbar dense color="#3F51B5" dark>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        color="#76ff03"
        @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"
      ></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-btn to="/" color="#76ff03" text>Vuetification</v-btn>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center">
        <v-badge bordered color="error" icon="mdi-lock" overlap>
          <v-btn class="white--text" color="error" depressed>
            Lock Account
          </v-btn>
        </v-badge>

        <div class="mx-3"></div>

        <v-badge
          bordered
          bottom
          color="deep-purple accent-4"
          dot
          offset-x="10"
          offset-y="10"
        >
          <v-avatar size="40">
            <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/2.jpg"></v-img>
          </v-avatar>
        </v-badge>

        <div class="mx-3"></div>

        <v-badge avatar bordered overlap>
          <template v-slot:badge>
            <v-avatar>
              <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/v.png"></v-img>
            </v-avatar>
          </template>

          <v-avatar size="40">
            <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/john.png"></v-img>
          </v-avatar>
        </v-badge>
      </v-row>
      <div class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon color="#76ff03">mdi-magnify</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon color="#76ff03">mdi-heart</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon color="#76ff03">mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn color="#76ff03" text>About</v-btn>
        <v-btn to="/contact" color="#76ff03" text>Contact</v-btn>
        <v-btn to="/login" color="#76ff03" text>Login</v-btn>
      </div>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      expand-on-hover
      app
      temporary
      right
      height="160px"
    >
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/78.jpg"></v-img>
        </v-list-item-avatar>

        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link>
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      items: [
        { title: "Home", icon: "mdi-ghost" },
        { title: "About", icon: "mdi-kabaddi" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.toolbar-item {
  color: #76ff03;
}
</style>
```

--- Footer.vue ---

```
plate>
  <v-app>
    <v-footer dark padless fixed>
      <v-card class="flex" text tile>
        <v-card-title class="teal">
          <strong class="subheading"
            >Get connected with us on social networks!</strong
          >

          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

          <v-btn v-for="icon in icons" :key="icon" class="mx-4" dark icon>
            <v-icon color="#76ff03" size="24px">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text class="text-center">
          <v-layout>
            <v-flex class="toolbar-item" v-for="(col, i) in rows" :key="i" xs3>
              <span class="body-2" v-text="col.title.toUpperCase()" />
              <div v-for="(child, i) in col.children" :key="i" v-text="child" />
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex class="toolbar-item" xd3 layout column>
              <span class="body-2">CONTACT</span>
              <div>
                <v-icon color="#76ff03" size="18px" class="mr-3"
                  >fa-home</v-icon
                >
                New York, NY 10012, US
              </div>
              <div>
                <v-icon color="#76ff03" size="18px" class="mr-3"
                  >fa-envelope</v-icon
                >
                info@example.com
              </div>
              <div>
                <v-icon color="#76ff03" size="18px" class="mr-3"
                  >fa-phone</v-icon
                >
                + 01 234 567 89
              </div>
              <div>
                <v-icon color="#76ff03" size="18px" class="mr-3"
                  >fa-print</v-icon
                >
                + 98 765 432 10
              </div>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <strong> {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} — Vuetify </strong>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    icons: [
      "fab fa-facebook",
      "fab fa-twitter",
      "fab fa-google-plus",
      "fab fa-linkedin",
      "fab fa-instagram"
    ],
    rows: [
      {
        title: "Company Name",
        children: [
          "Here you can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Produts",
        children: [
          "MDBootstrap",
          "MDWordPress",
          "BrandFlow",
          "BootstrapAngular"
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Useful Links",
        children: [
          "Your account",
          "Become an Affiliate",
          "Shipping Rates",
          "Helper"
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
};
</script>
<style scoped>
strong {
  color: #76ff03;
}
.toolbar-item {
  color: #76ff03;
}
</style
```

>

Comment: Why not `body { max-height: 100vh }`?

Comment: I'm not sure why but max-height = 100vh and min-height=100vh don't seem to be doing anything when i put them on a div element that has my components nested inside of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if the HTML content is larger than the window, the browser will create scrollbars and if it's smaller than the window there won't be a scroll. However, I don't think this is what you're really asking for. I think you're trying to change the window size itself.

---

I'm going to start by saying its **very bad practice to modify the size of the user's browser window**. You should work to make your content fit instead.

That said, as Vue.js and Vuetify are built on Javascript, and you'll need to write some custom JS to resize the browser window. The default `overflow` on the `<body>` tag (yes those exist in a Vue app) will take care of the scrolling...

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
```

Should be called after Vue has rendered the content to the screen so inside Vue's [Mounted Lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted).

Now, I assume the height of the content changes so you would want to grab the height of the Vue `app` div.

```
var newHeight = document.getElementById('app').innerHeight()
```

You also want to get the screen size so you don't make the window larger than the screen. You can get that height from the `screen` object.

```
var screenHeight = window.screen.height
```

so

```
if(newHeight < screenHeight){
   window.resizeTo('800px', newHeight);
} else {
   window.resizeTo('800px', screenHeight);
}
```

---

### Before you do this

You should know that most modern browsers BLOCK the `window.resizeTo()` function so again you should find a different solution to the problem.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. Since controlling the size of my content is most important, why is my scrollbar so long in this case? https://imgur.com/a/wfvvSmA

Comment: I'd have to see your full code (picture won't do it) but my guess is that you have something absolutely positioned or with a set height that's pushing everything off the screen. By default, containers are only as big as their content.

Comment: You might want to post that ("why is my scrollbar so long") as a question to SO. There's a chance you'll get some downvotes, but more eyes on your code are better.

Comment: are you saying that the code I have posted above isn't sufficient? What else would I add?

Comment: I'd need to see the rendered HTML and the CSS at least. Using something like Chrome's web inspector would be the easiest way to debug the issue but needs to run the code

Comment: Sorry for all of the noobie questions. I do appreciate your help. But, how will I locate the rendered HTML and CSS? Vue seems to compile everything I have above into a complicated and generally not decipherable (as far as finding where my code is in this source file) set of files. At least, this is what I see when I open the developer tools in google chrome (not vue devtools)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206300/discussion-between-a-here-and-now-and-bryce-howitson).

Answer (score 0):

You Can nest your content inside another div element.If max-height of your inner div is equal to the height of its container, scroll bar will never appear. if you want to see scroll bar use this.

```css
.scrollDiv {
    height:auto;
    max-height:150%;
    overflow:auto;   
}
```

Comment: The snippet would be more useful if it had HTML on which the CSS applied...